# Open a file in the same directory as the .go source file in Go

Tags: go

When in a source file $PWD/dir/src.go I use

```
os.Open("myfile.txt")
```

it looks for myfile.txt in $PWD (which looks normal).

Is there way to tell Go to look for myfile.txt in the same directory as src.go ? I need something like `__FILE__` in Ruby.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go is not an interpreted language so looking for a file in the same location as the source file doesn't make any sense. The go binary is compiled and the source file doesn't need to be present for the binary to run. Because of that Go doesn't come with an equivalent to **FILE**. The runtime.Caller function returns the file name at the time the binary was compiled.

I think perhaps if we understood why you actually wanted this functionality we could advise you better.

Comment: Good answer... Actually my Go program needs to load data from external files, and I want to be sure that it finds them, without having to set an absolute path to these files.

Comment: Probably you just want to set a convention for your app and have it load the files relative to where it runs from. or use the flags package and tell it where the files are on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

A possible substitute skeleton:

```
func __FILE__() (fn string) {
        _, fn, _, _ = runtime.Caller(0)
        return 
}
```

Details [here](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Caller).

Comment: Thanks jnml, I did not know runtime.Caller. I ended up following Jeremy's advice regarding how to load my files, but that's useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use package [osext](https://github.com/kardianos/osext)

It's providing function `ExecutableFolder()` that returns an absolute path to folder where the currently running program executable reside (useful for cron jobs). It's cross platform.

[Online documentation](http://godoc.org/github.com/kardianos/osext)

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/kardianos/osext"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    folderPath, err := osext.ExecutableFolder()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(folderPath)
}
```

You can also get full executable path (similar to `__FILE__`):

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/kardianos/osext"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    exeAbsolutePath, _ := osext.Executable()
    fmt.Println(exeAbsolutePath)
}
```